# Button onClick target is changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button with `fa` icon inside it, and I attached an onClick event (React)

If I click on the button, the target of the handler is the button itself. If I click on the `fa` icon that's inside the button, the target of the handler is the `i` tag that is the `fa` icon.

Example code:

```
<button onClick={changeViewType} value="boxes">
  <i className="fa fa-th" style={{color: '#26d6ff'}}/>
</button>
<button onClick={changeViewType} value="table">
  <i className="fa fa-list-ul"/>
</button>
```

Handler:

```
const changeViewType = selectedView => {
  console.log(selectedView.target.value)
}
```

Best way to handle this?
[image: gif]

Comment: Pass an argument to the function with the DOM object instead trying to get the target

Comment: Alternatively you can check the `tagName` before doing any action

Comment: But then the onClick would look like this `onClick={() => changeViewType('boxes'}` which is bad

Comment: well one you are clicking on the button, other you are clicking on the icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the target element is an `I`. If so, take the parent, if not keep taking the original target.

```
const changeViewType = selectedView => {
    target = selectedView.target.tagName == 'I'? selectedView.target.parentElement : selectedView.target;
    console.log(target.value)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target`.

From the MDN docs:

> It (`event.currentTarget`) always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached, as opposed to `event.target` which identifies the element on which the event occurred.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

Comment: This is the correct way of getting the element to which the event handler is attached ie the button in this case.